# PowerShell to get Azure AD Application Certificate information

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory

I've been trying to get Azure AD Application Certificate information, either the certificate or even just the thumbprint of the cert without any luck. I've been predominantly using Get-AzureADApplicationKeyCredential and get-AzureADApplication (AzureAD 2.0.2.76). There is a CustomKeyIdentifier in the results of both commands, which is a Byte[], but it isn't translatable to the thumbprint, and I can't really tell where it comes from. There is a Value property, which you would think had the certificate, but it is always null.

Is there away to get certificate information from an Azure AD Application?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I was using the wrong method of getting the thumbprint.

I should have run [system.convermt]::ToBase64String on the CustomKeyIdentifier property from either of Get-AzureADApplicationKeyCredential or get-AzureADApplication.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
 $aadApplicationCredentials = Get-AzADAppCredential -DisplayName $AADApplicationName
 $customerIdentifier = $aadApplicationCredentials[0].CustomKeyIdentifier
 [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($customerIdentifier)
```